# Scrolling Text in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I found one example from [this](http://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/?example=/css/codes/marquees/scrolling_text). It worked fine, but anybody knows how to make scrolling start immediately and after it finish scroll from right to left, immediately it start again. Because right now it wait about 3 second to start scrolling. Thanks.

Below is the CSS:

```
.example1 {
   height: 50px;    
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

.example1 h3 {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   line-height: 50px;
   text-align: center;

   /* Starting position */
   -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
   -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);  
   transform:translateX(100%);

   /* Apply animation to this element */    
   -moz-animation: example1 10s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: example1 10s linear infinite;
   animation: example1 10s linear infinite;
}

/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes example1 {
   0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
   100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
   0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
   100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@keyframes example1 {
   0%   { 
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateX(100%);        
  }

  100% { 
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateX(-100%); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example you have shown, all you need to do is add the following styles. `.example1 h3 {display: inline-block; width: auto;}` and change the animation to about 5s intervals.

The reason it scrolls late is because the width of the h3 is the full width of the screen/div with a centered text so it will be delayed by default.

Comment: After I added `.example1 h3` with `display: inline-block;` and changed width to `width: auto;`. The rest of styles, I just keep it. Then the result is, its not start scrolling from the end but in the center.